# How to fix MalformedURLException in Jenkinsfile

Tags: xml, jenkins, xml-parsing

I want to read a XML file using within Jenkins, directly from the Jenkinsfile.
The XML is well formed, something like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<node1>
  <element1>element</element1>
  <element2>elem</element2>
</node1>
```

and so on.

I'm reading this file with

```
def myfile = readFile(file: "filePath")
def myxml = new XmlParser().parse(myfile)
```

When I run this code I'm getting this error:

```
java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

It looks to me like it's trying to read a url although the file that I'm asking to be read is in my local machine and I'm writing that path based on that.

What could be the issue? Am I using the `XmlParser` in a wrong way?
My idea would be, after I read this file correctly, to change one field and then write the new file, so I'd appreciate any help about that step as well

Answer (score 0):

`XmlParser().parse(String)` accepts an [URI](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/xml/XmlParser.html#parse(java.lang.String)) where it will parse the content of the specified URI into a tree of Nodes. Instead, you have to use `XmlParser().parseText(String)` which will convert a String into a tree of Nodes.

```
def myfile = readFile(file: "$filePath")
def myxml = new XmlParser().parseText(myfile)
```

Comment: So, after reading as text, how could I update and write back the file? I'm looking for something like `def myxmlupdated = myxml.attribute = "value"` and write it back. Maybe with `writeFile(file: $filePath, text:myxmlupdate` What do you think?

Comment: @Carabes you don't have to assign it to a new variable. You can keep on updating the existing Node tree. `myxml.attribute = "value"` and then write to a file as you mentioned.